# PageLoadTimeout and implicitywait not working in chrome browser in mac

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

PageLoadtimeout and ImplicityWait are not working in Chrome browser in mac os.

These were working for me sometime back. But recently all the scripts started failing on chrome as browser doesn't wait for the pageload to complete.

I have downloaded the chromedriver from the below location and tried. But still it is not working.

http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.10/

- chromedriver_mac32.zip
- Mac OSX 10.9.4
- Chrome Version 36.0.1985.125
- Terminal output When chrome browser is launched

  Starting ChromeDriver (v2.10.267517) on port 7567
  Only local connections are allowed.

  Please let me know whether I need to download chromedriver from any other location (or) anything I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Is pageloadtimeout working in chrome for anyone? I have tried running scripts in chrome on Windows (thru VM) and it not working in windows either.